# Forward slashed removed in form id

Tags: java, forms, struts2, tags, struts

I am using Struts2(2.3.14) and a forward slash character included in a variable created in the java server-side code is being escaped to `_` after using it inside an struts form tag.

The code (JSP):

```
<div class="activetab" id="sub_${mytable}">
    <s:form id="%{mytable}" onsubmit="return go('%{mytable}');">
```

Transforms into the html:

```
<div class="activetab" id="sub_changePassword/execute">
    <s:form id="changePassword_execute" onsubmit="return go('changePassword/execute');">
```

Don't understand why I get "changePassword_execute" in the ID attribute instead of "changePassword/execute" ... (other attributes seem to be fine).

`id="${myTable}"` is not possible as `$` is not a valid wildcard within the form id attribute.

It's strange, Any thoughts?

Comment: Some code please? And formatting too.

Comment: It's been point out that this is a bad idea, if you insist... just use HTML, with struts2 property tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slash is not a valid DOM ID character:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name
- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name

I'd have to double-check, but it's probably the form tag converts illegal ID characters into underscores.

Comment: Thats right but is's been happening after updated the struts framework,, guess how to sort it.

Comment: Don't use invalid DOM identifiers?

Comment: After updating the struts version it seems the framework "escapes" the forward slash (I guess because of a security issue). As one possible solution just replaced the struts form by a normal html form, as changuing the id had some other problems.

Comment: @kandan Using an invalid DOM identifier could have some other problems too, like browser differences, JS accessibility, etc.